# probability and convariance

Tags: probability

[image]

How can I calculate the probability and prove the desired result that $X, Y$ uncorrelatd? and whether independent? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if for all $x$, $y$, 
$$\Pr((X=x) \cap (Y=y))=\Pr(X=x)\Pr(Y=y).$$

So for our particular $X$ and $Y$, we **do not** have independence. For the probability of $4$ Aces is non-zero, as is the probability of $0$ spades. 
So the product of the probabilities is non-zero.

But the probability of $4$ Aces **and** no spades is $0$. For if we have $4$ Aces, for sure we have at least one spade!

For the uncorrelatedness, imagine dealing the cards one at a time. Let $X_i=1$ if the $i$th card is an Ace, and $0$ otherwise. Similarly, let $Y_i=1$ if the $i$-th card is a spade, and $0$ otherwise. Then 
$$XY=(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{13})(Y_1+Y_2+\cdots +Y_{13}).$$
Expand, and show that for all $i$ and $j$ we have $E(X_iX_j)=E(X_i)E(Y_j)$.

Comment: how do you prove that they are uncorrelated?

Comment: you only answered the easy part

Comment: The other part is doable, by linearity of expectation. There are a few calculations that need to be made, but only for drawing single cards.